# Отсеить строки сгруппированных полей Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос вида

```
SELECT login, subs_id, ip, login_out 
FROM cam.test 
WHERE subs_id IN (SELECT subs_id 
                  FROM cam.test 
                  where login_out > 0 and (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - login_out) < 30
                  GROUP BY subs_id 
                  HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
                  and login_out > 0
                  )
order by login;
```

выхлоп такой

```
login         |subs_id|ip            |login_out |
--------------|-------|--------------|----------|
birolev1      |     46|95.3.25.168   |1578426551|
birolev2      |     46|95.3.125.170  |1578426551|
bocskori1     |    227|16.118.43.11  |1578426549|
bocskori2     |    227|16.118.43.11  |1578426549|
bugia         |    371|95.3.25.169   |1578426549|
bugia2        |    371|95.3.25.169   |1578426553|
```

Нужно дописать запрос, чтоб убрать те строки, где ip идентичный в полях с одинаковым subs_id, тоесть нужно получить

```
login         |subs_id|ip            |login_out |
--------------|-------|--------------|----------|
birolev1      |     46|95.3.25.168   |1578426551|
birolev2      |     46|95.3.125.170  |1578426551|
```

Comment: Используйте `INNER JOIN` с таблицей, `ip | кол-во вхождений`, где количество вхождений `= 1`

Comment: Убрать одинаковые ip либо получить только те ip которые встречаются 1 раз?

Comment: @becouse _Убрать одинаковые ip либо получить только те ip которые встречаются 1 раз?_ 
нужно убрать те строки, где ip идентичный в полях с одинаковым subs_id

Comment: `WHERE login_out > 0 ... GROUP BY subs_id HAVING ... login_out > 0` - это шутка?

Comment: Версию MySQL озвучьте - это немножко важно в данном случае.

Comment: @Akina _WHERE login_out > 0 ... GROUP BY subs_id HAVING ... login_out > 0 - это шутка?_ никак нет, именно так работает запрос правильно

Comment: @Akina _Версию MySQL озвучьте - это немножко важно в данном случае._  5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log

Comment: WHERE отсеял ВСЕ записи с `login_out <= 0`. Объясните мне - откуда они могли появиться после группировки?

Comment: @Akina _WHERE отсеял ВСЕ записи с login_out <= 0. Объясните мне - откуда они могли появиться после группировки?_ к сожалению он не отсеивает

Comment: В комментарии к ответу Вы сообщаете, что *получаю ошибку 21:22:58 Ошибка ядра: Error( 1055 )*. Т.е. only_full_group_by = ON. Но если так - должна быть та же ошибка на показанный запрос - использованное в HAVING `login_out` тоже ни там, ни там. Где-то Вы явно что-то недоговариваете. *к сожалению он не отсеивает* И опять не верю. Чудес не бывает.

Comment: Сделайте выгрузку скриптов и создайте fiddle, воспроизводящий ситуацию. Сейчас - не вопрос, а сплошные неразрешимые противоречия.

Comment: _В комментарии к ответу..._ это ошибка на запрос, написанный @Ainar-G

Comment: О! всё ещё хуже! [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=771fd1cbc4867a70af79b7421db6cb36). В `HAVING COUNT(id) > 1 and login_out > 0` поле `login_out` берётся не из таблицы в подзапросе, а из таблицы основного запроса, т.е. подзапрос - коррелированный. Так что это условие вообще нужно переносить в основной запрос.

Comment: _Сделайте выгрузку скриптов..._ [фидл](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wbiUaLibEsA9y2WyqRg411/0)

Comment: Вот правильный текст исходного запроса - [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wbiUaLibEsA9y2WyqRg411/1). Теперь примените к нему метод из ответа @Ainar-G - получите решение.

Comment: _получите решение..._ получаю ошибку(( [фидл](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wbiUaLibEsA9y2WyqRg411/2)

Answer (score 1):

Почему не добавить ещё одну группировку с `HAVING`?

```sql
SELECT MAX(login)
     , MAX(subs_id)
     , MAX(login_out)
     , ip
  FROM cam.test 
 WHERE subs_id IN (
         SELECT subs_id 
           FROM cam.test 
          WHERE login_out > 0 AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - login_out) < 30
          GROUP BY subs_id 
         HAVING COUNT(id) > 1 AND login_out > 0
       )
 GROUP BY ip
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
 ORDER BY login
;
```

Comment: получаю ошибку 21:22:58 Ошибка ядра: Error( 1055 ) 42000: "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'cam.test.login' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: А, да, агрегатные функции.  Тут можно использовать любые, так как нам интересны только с `COUNT(*) = 1`.  Я поправил, используя `MAX`.

Comment: получаю также ошибку 1055

Comment: @ryan88  [У меня работает](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cp2bfd4CgqAb5dVtNqcMiW/0).  Всё точно так же?  Если да, то вынесите пример целиком в вопрос с полным текстом ошибки.

Comment: вы наверно не понимаете меня, **нужно убрать те строки, где ip идентичный в полях с одинаковым subs_id**

Comment: Так вы в вопросе ни слова о `subs_id` не написали.  Перепишите вопрос, упомянув **целиком** условие запроса и показав разницу между моими результатами и теми, что должны получиться у вас.

Comment: Нужно дописать запрос, чтоб отсеять те строки, где все ip идентичный в полях с одинаковым subs_id, тоесть строки
'
|login|subs_id|ip        |
|a1   |41         |1.1.1.1|
|a2   |41         |1.1.1.1|
'
нужно отсеять